# How to distinguish protocols in a TCP/UDP payload?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ip

IP packets have a 8-bit header (`Protocol` for v4 and `Next Header` in v6) which determines which transport-layer protocol is used in the payload. For example if it's 6, the payload is a TCP segment, and if it's 17 then that is an UDP one.

But how do we find which applicative-layer protocol is used inside a TCP or UDP payload? There is no such header available that serves the same purpose. How do we distinguish a payload that encapsulates a HTTP request with another that encapsulates a SMTP mail? Is it the port used? If so, if I send a SMTP mail on port 80 instead of 25, will it be interpreted as a HTTP request instead of a SMTP mail?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You put it into the payload, if you're really using the same connection for multiple application protocols. I suggest this is rather rare. More usually you only have to distinguish different message types within the same overall application protocol.

Comment: And sometimes there is no protocol at all, just the actual data, for example the contents of a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If so, if I send a SMTP mail on port 80 instead of 25, will it be interpreted as a HTTP request instead of a SMTP mail?

There is usually no specific marker which defines the application protocol. It is instead a question of what the communication peers expect from each other.

If you send a HTTP request to an SMTP server the server will try to interpret the information as SMTP - **because this is what it expects**. Since a HTTP request looks differently from SMTP the server will somehow complain, like simply closing the connection or sending a SMTP error response back - because this is an SMTP server which speaks and expects SMTP. The client send will try to interpret the server SMTP response as a HTTP response - **because this is what it expects**. Of course it will fail doing this since SMTP looks very different from HTTP.

Comment: Ok, but if a chunk of data could be interpreted in 2 different protocols and it would match perfectly for the `len` headers and so on, then this data could be interpreted as a valid packet by the communication peers of the 2 protocols, right?

Comment: @JacopoStanchi: again, it is all up to the expectations. If what a recipient gets matches what it expects it will be interpreted as belonging to the expected protocol. Of course, the sender might have intended something completely different.